# Implementation of BFS

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I have implemented Breadth First Search. The adjacency matrix(adj[][]) represents the relationship among different nodes and the nodes are stored in nodes[].

However, I do not get the required traversal. Please help me out. Below is my code. There are no syntax errors. It is probably a logical error that I am not able to find out by debugging.

```
insert(nodes[0]);
nos = nos + 1;
visited[nos] = nodes[0];
while(front != -1)
{
 char ch = remove();
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    if(ch == nodes[i])
    {
               pos = i;
    }
 }
 for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
 {
         if(adj[j][pos] == 1)
         {
            for(int k=0;k<=nos;k++)
            {
                    if(visited[k] == nodes[j])
                    {
                        goto end;
                    }
            }
            nos = nos + 1;
            visited[nos] = nodes[j];
            insert(nodes[j]);
            end:continue;
         }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Why insert `nodes[someindex]` and then have to look it up again, instead of just inserting `someindex` ? Also - why are you inserting to `visited[]` only from index 1?

Comment: Ok, what is the content of `nodes[]`? is it unique? because all your `visited[]` comparisons would only work then. Why not keep the indices in `visited[]`?

Comment: nodes[] contains all unique nodes.

Comment: i want to know what is wrong with my method.. is there any error?

Comment: Aside from design issues as I mentioned (and also the goto, brrr..), i'm out of ideas. I also don't write what's wrong with the result. I suggest you check with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it seems to be working for me

```
def bfs(graph, start, goal):
  if start == goal:
      return None

  frontier = [start]
  explored = []
  num_explored = 0
  while len(frontier) > 0:
     node = frontier.pop(0)

     explored.append(node)
     for edge in networkx.edges(graph, node):
         child = State(graph, node)

         if (child not in explored) and (child not in frontier):
             if child == goal:
                 print "Path found in BFS"
                 return child
             else:
                 frontier.append(child)
             num_explored = num_explored + 1
  print "BFS path failed"

  return None
```